# WCF and Queuing calls

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, wcf-client

Have been playing with WCF IIS & self hosted solution (i think i said that right). Basically, copies of the same codebase, hosted websites are talking to each other.

When an event occurs, I need to connect a client to a number of endpoints to send a message. I would like to queue those calls and have them occur async.

I was wondering if I should place in a msmq, either the client ready to call the method or an endpoint and message or something. Then have a windows services pick jobs off the queue to send out messages.

Am I going down some legacy path and missing out on some functionality that WCF has?

Some clues as the best way to do this?

thanks

Comment: As you may know that Client config can have multiple endpoints for the same contract with different addresses. So based on the event you can use the specific endpoint. Is queuing a strict requirement here.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect use case for a publish/subscribe service bus such as NServiceBus.  Basically you dispatch a message from your website endpoint (using NServiceBus on top of MSMQ).  Another endpoint makes some decisions based upon the message received from the website and then [publishes](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/) the results of that decision in the form of an event to all interested subscribers.